# How to grab a Dictionary and convert it to a list of strings from another function?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I am stuck trying to grab this Dictionary that I set, and then convert it to an array so that I am able to use it in another function, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the problem retrieving the dictionary, or setting the dictionary?

Comment: Are you getting a compile error? if so, what is it? If not, what is the result and what were you expecting?

Comment: `snapshot.keys as? String` will always fail because `keys` is an array or a kind of slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull the keys into an array in multiple ways:

```
let newArray = Array(snapshot.keys.map{ $0 })
```

You can also combine them both

```
let array = snapshot.keys.array.map { "\($0) \(snapshot[$0]!)" }
```